# d3 creating A multiseries chart using d3

Tags: d3.js

I am new to d3 and javascript. I need your help how can I prepare a chart using the code below.

What are the changes I need to make in the code if I have data in form of a javascript function with Arryays of no
say for example:
var x= new Array()
no ranging from 1 to 100
 and then I have values for y1,y2,y3 also as an array of numbers.
Please help so that I can use the below code to create a multiseries graph.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<style>

body {
  font: 10px sans-serif;
}

.axis path,
.axis line {
  fill: none;
  stroke: #000;
  shape-rendering: crispEdges;
}

.x.axis path {
  display: none;
}

.line {
  fill: none;
  stroke: steelblue;
  stroke-width: 1.5px;
}

</style>
<body>
<script src="http://d3js.org/d3.v3.js"></script>
<script>

var margin = {top: 20, right: 80, bottom: 30, left: 50},
    width = 960 - margin.left - margin.right,
    height = 500 - margin.top - margin.bottom;

var parseDate = d3.time.format("%Y%m%d").parse;

var x = d3.time.scale()
    .range([0, width]);

var y = d3.scale.linear()
    .range([height, 0]);

var color = d3.scale.category10();

var xAxis = d3.svg.axis()
    .scale(x)
    .orient("bottom");

var yAxis = d3.svg.axis()
    .scale(y)
    .orient("left");

var line = d3.svg.line()
    .interpolate("basis")
    .x(function(d) { return x(d.date); })
    .y(function(d) { return y(d.temperature); });

var svg = d3.select("body").append("svg")
    .attr("width", width + margin.left + margin.right)
    .attr("height", height + margin.top + margin.bottom)
  .append("g")
    .attr("transform", "translate(" + margin.left + "," + margin.top + ")");

d3.tsv("data.tsv", function(error, data) {
  color.domain(d3.keys(data[0]).filter(function(key) { return key !== "date"; }));

  data.forEach(function(d) {
    d.date = parseDate(d.date);
  });

  var cities = color.domain().map(function(name) {
    return {
      name: name,
      values: data.map(function(d) {
        return {date: d.date, temperature: +d[name]};
      })
    };
  });

  x.domain(d3.extent(data, function(d) { return d.date; }));

  y.domain([
    d3.min(cities, function(c) { return d3.min(c.values, function(v) { return v.temperature; }); }),
    d3.max(cities, function(c) { return d3.max(c.values, function(v) { return v.temperature; }); })
  ]);

  svg.append("g")
      .attr("class", "x axis")
      .attr("transform", "translate(0," + height + ")")
      .call(xAxis);

  svg.append("g")
      .attr("class", "y axis")
      .call(yAxis)
    .append("text")
      .attr("transform", "rotate(-90)")
      .attr("y", 6)
      .attr("dy", ".71em")
      .style("text-anchor", "end")
      .text("Temperature (ºF)");

  var city = svg.selectAll(".city")
      .data(cities)
    .enter().append("g")
      .attr("class", "city");

  city.append("path")
      .attr("class", "line")
      .attr("d", function(d) { return line(d.values); })
      .style("stroke", function(d) { return color(d.name); });

  city.append("text")
      .datum(function(d) { return {name: d.name, value: d.values[d.values.length - 1]}; })
      .attr("transform", function(d) { return "translate(" + x(d.value.date) + "," + y(d.value.temperature) + ")"; })
      .attr("x", 3)
      .attr("dy", ".35em")
      .text(function(d) { return d.name; });
});

</script>
```

Comment: var dataset = {
  apples: [53245, 28479, 19697, 24037, 40245],
  oranges: [53245, 28479, 19697, 24037, 40245],
  lemons: [53245, 28479, 19697, 24037, 40245],
  pears: [53245, 28479, 19697, 24037, 40245],
  pineapples: [53245, 28479, 19697, 24037, 40245],
};

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to convert your data structure into something that can be used directly to draw the lines, e.g. through

```
var pairs = d3.entries(dataset);
```

Complete example [here](http://jsfiddle.net/FMYLN/).

Comment: Thanks for the answer,But wen I tried to upload it I am getting something like A SINGLE LINE.How can I get a multiline graph

Comment: The data for all your series is the same, hence the lines overlap.

Comment: Thanks for the answer,Can this also for the multidonut chart and Multistacked chart. Can you please suggest Any link so that I can understand d3 better.

Comment: There are plenty of tutorials on the D3 website.

Comment: same data set for multidonut chart

Comment: Well, I've given you a start with this one, I'm sure you can figure it out from here :)

Comment: I have one more Question . Can I also give the data as   data=[                          ["apples",3333,33,3545,334,55],["pineapples",99,330,30030,339] what changes do I have to make so the d3.entries will return the values as d.key and d.value?

Comment: You can use any data format you like as long as you know how to transform it. If you don't, I recommend sticking with the one you have.

Comment: Can you suggest me the site from where I can read  how to tranform data

Comment: There's no specific site -- this is a general programming thing really.